# iText Read HTML Tag when Converting HTML to PDF with ConvertToElements

Tags: c#, .net, itext, itext7

I want to create a TOC with iText7 and my document is composed from multiple HTML strings. When I parse this strings with `HtmlConverter.ConvertToElements` I want to check foreach element if it's a H1 in order to add that to TOC but I'm having a hard time to achive this. I am unable to get the role from DefaultAccessibilityProperties of an element.

The information that I want is here in `tagProperties.role`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it. Cast your element as a div an then get the tagname via Role.

```
var div = element as Div;
if (div.GetAccessibilityProperties().GetRole() == "H1") title = true;
```

and bonus helper to get content from an element in order to populate TOC:

```
private static string GetContent(IElement element)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    if (element is Text) builder.Append(((Text)element).GetText());
    if (element is IAbstractElement)
        foreach (var child in (element as IAbstractElement).GetChildren())
            builder.Append(GetContent(child));
    return builder.ToString();
}
```